# I have a setTimeout function and bug in my code

Tags: jquery

I am trying to do this code but it is giving me error and the error is not clear. please help me what is error in this code.

```
$("#sess").click(function(){    
 if(S == 0){
   var temp = SL;
   while(SL != 0){ 
     if(temp == SL){
       setTimeout(function(){
         temp = SL--;
       }, 100);
      }
      $("#Time").html(SL);     
      //S=1;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Please add the screenshot of your error.

Comment: Just include the necessary html part of the code with the details of error that your are getting? Explain your problem clearly so that the viewers got the good idea about your problem and able to find a better solution quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just have a syntax error, I moved the `);` code.  Try this:

```
$("#sess").click(function(){    
 if(S == 0){
   var temp = SL;
   while(SL != 0){ 
     if(temp == SL){
       setTimeout(function(){
         temp = SL--;
       }, 100);
      }
      $("#Time").html(SL);     
      //S=1;
    }
  }
});
```